# Highlight active menu item

Tags: jquery, substr, lastindexof

I have a menu created by a list. I would like to be able to highlight the current menu item.

With this script I'm able to match the last bit of the url (everything after the last `/`), but I need the script to match the two previous folders in the url as well. So instead of e.g.`index.html`, I'd like to grab `/folder1/folder2/index.html`.

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $(".nav li a").each(function () {
        //console.log(url);
        if ($(this).attr("href") == url) $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
});


//Markup:

<ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="/folder1/folder2/index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/folder1/folder2/about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/folder1/folder2/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I modify the script to match more parts of the url?

Comment: window.location.pathname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one should work:

```
$(function () {
  var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $('[href$="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass("active");
});
```